# CRM2011 Opportunity attributes CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, and New_PrimarySalesContactId

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 while creating opportunity, when assigning values to  CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, and New_PrimarySalesContactId for Opportunity getting compile time error says all the above properties are read only. In CRM 4.0, while creating opportunity, values can be assigned the above properties. How can I assign values to above attributes while creating opportunity through code.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the 'Override Created on or Created by for records during data import' permission it is misleading to say the least: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadcrmsupport/archive/2012/08/01/the-truth-about-override-created-on-or-created-by-for-records-during-data-import.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[There is only one way](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/a92b252f-5164-40c4-94e8-3d78f43f7670) to set CreatedBy: you have to impersonate the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150987(v=MSDN.10).aspx

Comment: Here is [a sample of using Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx)